# How to get rid of odors in wood?

Tags: wood, pest-control, smell

My attic floor was home to nesting mice for years before I bought the house. I've kept the mice away, but the smell hasn't lessened after a year of ventilation.

Short of replacing the wood, is there any way to remove the smell?

Comment: bleach works well for a lot of organic-based smells. considering the price/effort, i think it's worth a shot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a few things:

1) Treat with odor neutralizer.  Pet stores and hardware stores usually sell products designed to remove odors.  For set in smells this may not be 100% effective.

2) Seal the wood. If you don't intend to use this surface as a final surface, a coat of sealant style paint (Killz is my brand of preference) will not remove the odor but it will lock it in the wood so you won't smell it again.